# How to deal with multiple line loop-like blocks in bison for 3 address code generation?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to create a compiler and one of the cases that I want to tackle is somthing like this:

```
i = 3
a = 0
repeat i - 1 do
  a = a + i
done
```

The expected output would be:

```
i = 3
a = 0
$t1 := i SUBI 1
$t2 := 0
LINE_NUMBER: $t3 := a ADDI i
$t2 := $t2 ADDI 1
IF $t2 LTI $t1 GOTO LINE_NUMBER
```

But no matter what I try my code won't even run if I add one of these blocks to my test file. The idea is to not add backpatching, just manually capture the line Im at once I detect a `REPEAT expr DO ENDLINE` line and then the comparation.

As of now I have a basic 3 address code generator that makes use of code in c to deal with simple operations that deal with things like `a = a + 2` and a emet function that sends the PUT, HALT, PARAM and generally generates the instructions.
I tried adding things like this to my y file:

```
REPEAT expr do '\n' input DONE  {}

iterative : REPEAT expr DO ENDLINE sentences_list DONE ENDLINE {
        salt = ln_inst; 
        emet(NULL,0,NULL,"END\n",NULL);
    }

REPEAT expr capture DO ENDLINE sentences_list DONE ENDLINE {}

capture : DO { line_number = current_line }
```

The main idea is for a program to be made of a list_sentences and then each sentence have a possible type (assignment, operation, and lastly this iterative block, which in itself can contain a list of sentences as the loop).
If needed will post my files for easier understanding of my current lex file and .y, since Im not sure if Im getting my point across.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to write a one-pass compiler, right? Since if you build an AST and codegen from that, the problem just goes away. Are you familiar with mid-rule actions? That's what you need... (The parse->AST then AST->code is a lot easier in the long run, though.)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've looked at mid-rule actions and they might be what I need for the processing of the loop, but I'm still having trouble with the compiler accepting the fact that there are a group of sentences in the middle of the block, but I can recognise the block just fine.

Comment: Unless you actually share your grammar (or a reduced but self-contained subset), there's no way to provide a suggestion.